# How to create buttons that appear in UITableView

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I'm making a menu using a UITableView Controller and I need to create buttons that appear in the very first cell or spot of the table and the very end of the table view. The table view also holds 10 cells at runtime (it's the maximum number of cells).  Each button will present another view controller.

I've recently tried using viewforSectionInHeader but had no luck.

How can I create two buttons in a UITableView , one in the first position and one at the very end? The very last button is supposed to be an icon like a plus sign too.

Comment: you can use view controller. add a view with two button .below put tableview. or give design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
let topButton = UIButton()
let bottomButton = UIButton()

self.table.tableHeaderView = topButton
self.table.tableFooterView = bottomButton
```

Simply using the table's `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` is all you need to do.

Comment: I suppose I like your response more... have a like ;)

Comment: @penatheboss like ;)

Comment: Thanks guys! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum cell count is 10 
set

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {  
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 12
}
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = _tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! yourCell

   if indexPath.row ==0 || 11{

  //show button First row or  last
  // add target to button for click also set tag for the button to identify which button clicked 

   }
    else  {
  //hide button
  }
 return cell
}
```

create a tableview cell with button and label as per your design.
based on the row you hide button or other controls.
add outlet.

Comment: based on what condition?

Answer (score -1):

Well add the buttons you want to have on both cells to your prototype cell but make them hidden. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath function check the indexPath.row value. If it's the first row or the last row then set the hidden value to be false. If it's not the first or last row then don't change the hidden value.

You'll need to know which rows are hidden though. So if you have 10 rows then the 9th and 0th value for indexPath.row needs to enable visibility on the buttons

Comment: Making the buttons hidden works, but it would be far superior to make a different cell. One cell would have buttons and the other would not.